# Number of outcomes times probability of failure is number of failures?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I was hoping someone could spread some insight on why this is true?  Suppose that in some situation, there are n! number of possible outcomes.  Also, suppose that p is the probability of failure of all n events (i.e. a matching problem where no one picks their correct match), then it results that the number of outcomes that are failures is n!*p.

I was maybe trying to relate it to the expected value for a binomial random variable, but perhaps we cannot relate expected value to here, since n!*p is the number of ways, not the expected number of ways?

Thanks!

Comment: The setup of the experiment is not well-formed. When there are $n!$ possible outcomes, the size of your samples space $|\Omega|=n!$. You then say "$p$ is the probability of failure of __all__ $n$ events", but there are many more than $n$ events.

Comment: @jesterII I understand your confusion, that's why I added the example.  The setting of the experiment is a matching problem, where n people throw something into a pile and then each go back and select something at random.  Then, if p is the probability that after n people have selected, that no one picked their item... then there are n!*p ways this can happen.  Does that clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a sample space of $N$ *equally likely* outcomes, and the number of outcomes that result in failure in $F$, then the probability $p$ of failure is given by 
$$p=\frac{F}{N}.$$
This can be rewritten as $F=Np$.

**Remark:** The example you have in mind is that we consider the $n!$ permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. Under the right assumptions, these $n!$ permutations are equally likely. Let $D_n$ be the number of [*derangements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. If $p$ is the probability that a randomly chosen permutation is a derangement, then $p=\frac{D_n}{n!}$ and therefore $D_n=n!p$.

Comment: Wow, that is so simple!  Thank you very much!

Comment: The original question does not specify that all outcomes are equally likely. Is this implicit somewhere?

Comment: @jesterII: The original question indeed does not specify equally likely outcomes. That is why I stressed the assumption in the answer. Perhaps it should have been boldfaced. Without the "equally likely" assumption, the desired result need not hold.